# jquery first click is not working, further clicks works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code jquery code... first time click not working, further clicks works and also in iphone safari nothing happening. Do we need to add anything specific to safari browser. Any help will be appreciated.

**CSS**

```
p.expand-one {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        p.content-one {
            display:none;
        }

        p.expand-2 {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        p.content-2 {
            display:none;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sitesection">
    <p class="expand-one" onclick="dostuff('.expand-one','.content-one');" > + Click Here To Display The Content </p>
    <p class="content-one">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
    <p class="content-one">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... "</p>

    <p class="expand-2" onclick="dostuff('.expand-2','.content-2');"> + Click Here To Display The Content </p>
    <p class="content-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
    <p class="content-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... "</p>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
  function dostuff(classname1, classname2) {

      $(classname1).unbind().click( function(){
        $(classname2).slideToggle('fast');
        $(classname1).text(($(classname1).text() == '- Click Here To Display The Content') ? '+ Click Here To Display The Content':'- Click Here To Display The Content')
       });

  }
</script>
```

Thanks..

Comment: You are assigning click handler in first click.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you only add the `click()` event handler *after* the first call to your `doStuff()` function. Remove the `click()` call.

```
function dostuff(classname1, classname2) {
    $(classname2).slideToggle('fast');
    $(classname1).text(($(classname1).text() == '- Click Here To Display The Content') ? '+ Click Here To Display The Content':'- Click Here To Display The Content')
}
```

Or better yet, remove the ugly and outdated `on*` event attributes and attach your events using unobtrusive Javascript. As you're already using jQuery, here's how you do that:

```
<div class="sitesection">
    <p class="expand"> + Click Here To Display The Content </p>
    <p class="content">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
    <p class="content">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... "</p>

    <p class="expand"> + Click Here To Display The Content </p>
    <p class="content">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
    <p class="content">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... "</p>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.expand').click(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('.expand').slideToggle('fast');
            $(this).text(function(i, text) {
            return text.trim().charAt(0) == '-' ? '+ Click Here To Display The Content' : '- Click Here To Display The Content';
        });
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pv7g5veo/)

Comment: Better suggestion would be to use `jQuery-attached-events` than `inline-events`... I guess :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory and Rayon, it was very quick. Any idea why this is not working in Iphone safari, Since I am sending this file as a link to email, users will click from iphone email

Comment: No, we are uploading the dynamically created html file to sharepoint and sharepoint link will be provided to the user in email. When we click the url in email page opens up but expand action is not happening.

Comment: I fixed the issue, it was due to fire wall. Thanks again for all the help.